# 500 Internal Server Error with Rails 6 and React as front-end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm having this error

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-03-30 16:20:14 +0800
Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
  Rendering products/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered products/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 70)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 45ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 18735)
```

I'm using Rails 6 and React as the front-end. I did include a dummy `index.html.erb` to Rails view.

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>AnimeStore</title> 
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %> 
    <%= csp_meta_tag %> 
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %> 
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application'%> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> 
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'index' %> 
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'index',media: 'all' %> 
  </head> 
  <body> <%= yield %> </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide the content of ```index.html.erb```?

Comment: It's empty but this is the content of application.html.erb `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AnimeStore</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application'%>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'index' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'index',media: 'all' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
`

Comment: try to move '<%= javascript_pack_tag 'index' %>' to ```index.html.erb```

Comment: I tried but it still did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Rails 6 and devise. This comment in Github was useful: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/38820#issuecomment-604058068

Comment: Even though `6-0-stable` _is_ `6.0.2.2` (as of this comment), this still fixed my identical issue. Thanks!